# AWT and Swing components in NetBeans

Tags: java, swing, netbeans, awt

Scenario : In NetBeans, you create `Swing` components via drag & drop and customize some properties via the given GUI.

Question : Later on, If you see the generated code of these components, either in `source` or by by right-clicking the component and selecting `customize code`, we can see that the property changes are implemented via AWT. Why is this so?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mentioned in [*Using Top-Level Containers*](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/toplevel.html),

> Each program that uses Swing components has at least one top-level
>   container. This top-level container is the root of a containment
>   hierarchy — the hierarchy that contains all of the Swing components
>   that appear inside the top-level container.

[`java.awt.Container`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Container.html), an AWT `Componenet`, is that container.

Addendum: This overview suggests how pervasively the interface [`java.beans.PropertyChangeListener`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/beans/class-use/PropertyChangeListener.html) is used throughout AWT and Swing.